# ImportError: cannot import name 'countVectorizer' from 'sklearn.feature_extraction.text

Tags: python, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

**CODE**

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import countVectorizer
count=countVectorizer
docs=np.array(['The sun is shinning',
               'The weather is sweet',
               'The sun is shinning,The weather is sweet, and one and one is two'])
bag= count.fit_transform(docs)
```

**ERROR Output**

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e322748c3b4c> in <module>
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import countVectorizer
      3 count=countVectorizer
      4 docs=np.array(['The sun is shinning',
      5                'The weather is sweet',

ImportError: cannot import name 'countVectorizer' from 'sklearn.feature_extraction.text' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py)
```

**statement**
     I am getting this  error help me to resolve it.I am using jupyter notebook in anaconda navigator prompt.I installed the latest version of scikit-learn but also I got the same import error. Then also installed and uninstalled the scikit-learn using Anaconda command prompt

Comment: It's `CountVectorizer` not `countVectorizer` (Python is case sensitive).

Comment: Thanks @ayhan I missed that one it worked with some additional changes to the code

Answer (score 1):

> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

is working